# How Do I Link in Comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I'm sorry if this has an obvious answer, but I haven't been able to find it.

How do I link in a comment? I know that if I paste the URL, it will automatically become a link. But I've seen several people link text. What's the code for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same as in an answer:

```
[Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)
```

...becomes this:

[Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)

It's just not as obvious since there's no toolbar. There's more about how markdown works on our [editing help](https://writers.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.